# Pass parameter from one Powershell function to another

Tags: powershell

I’m new to powershell and development in general.  I’m trying to write a script that will email a contact once a file exceeds a certain size.  I have two individual functions both working separately (one to check the file size and one to generate a file for sendmail to use) but I can’t get them to interact.

I want to execute the function CheckSize and if the variable $ExceedsSize gets set to 1 then call function SendMail otherwise the script should finish with no other action.

I’ve searched through the forums but couldn’t find anything to apply to what I’m doing.

```
   ##Check file to see if it is over a particular size and then send email once threshold is reached.

param( 
    [string]$SiteName = "TestSite",                                                 #Name of Site (No Spaces)
    [string]$Path = "\\NetworkPath\Directory",                                      #Path of directory to check
    [int]$FileSizeThreshold = 10,                                                   #Size in MB that will trigger a notification email
    [string]$Contacts = "MyEmail@email.com"
    )    

CLS

##Creates variable $ExceedsSize based on newest file in folder.
Function CheckSize {
IF ((GCI $Path -Filter *.txt | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1 | Measure-Object -property Length -sum).sum / 1000000 -gt $FileSizeThreshold) {$ExceedsSize = 1}
ELSE {$ExceedsSize = 0}

Write-Host $ExceedsSize
}


Function SendMail {
    Param([string]$Template, [string]$Contacts, [string]$WarnTime)

    $EmailLocation = "\\NetworkPath\Scripts\File_$SiteName.txt"

    #Will Generate email from params
        New-Item $EmailLocation -type file -force -value "From: JMSIssue@emails.com`r
To: $Contacts`r
Subject: $SiteName file has exceeded the maximum file size threshold of $FileSizeThreshold MB`r`n"

    #Send Email
    #CMD /C "$SendMail\sendmail.exe -t < $EmailLocation"

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before or after your `Write-Host $ExceedsSize`:

```
return $ExceedsSize
```

Add this to the bottom:

```
$var = CheckSize

if ($var -eq 1){
    SendMail
}
```

**Explanation**
You have two functions, but don't actually run them. The part at the bottom does that.
Your CheckSize function does not return the `$ExceedsSize` for the rest of the function; by default it remains within the scope of the function. `return x` means the variable is passed back to the main script. `$var =` means it is assigned ot that variable.

Comment: I removed Write-Host $ExceedsSize completely and replaced it with Return $ExceedsSize.  After that, adding your IF onto the bottom made perfect sense and works just like I wanted it.  It didn't occur to me to assign a variable to the output of the function.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it's now working!  As per the other answer, another approach is to call `SendMail` from within `CheckSize`.  Another way - which you should avoid as generally it's bad practice - is to assign a variable global scope: `$global:ExceedsSize` and then check the value of `$ExceedsSize` within `SendMail`. [about_scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) is worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

Per the other answer, you need to `return $ExceedsSize` instead of using `Write-Host` (see here for why Write-Host is considered harmful: http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

You could alternatively call the `SendMail` function from within the CheckSize function, e.g:

```
 if ($ExceedsSize -eq 1){SendMail}
```

You will still need to call the CheckSize function somewhere also:

```
CheckSize
```

You might also want to give consideration to naming your functions in the verb-noun style of the built in cmdlets. This really helps make their use more explicit to you and others. When choosing a verb, its best to stick to the approved list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx

And also to use names that are fairly unique to avoid possible conflicts.

I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
Get-NewestFileSize
```

(although that's what it should then return)

and

```
Send-CCSMail
```

Comment: I've gone from Admin to Help Desk to L2 Support and have ended up as a developer.  I've been on a figure it out path for quite a while now.  The Verb-Noun naming convention makes a lot of sense.